# Android Log.d not displaying because of textView.getText().toString()

Tags: android, textview, android-log

The first two logs display fine, but the last one doesn't show up. Even if the second parameter of the last log has an issue, I'm still confused why the log doesn't just display with an error or something. Any help is appreciated.

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    TextView country = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.country);
    Log.d("t1", "t1");
    Log.d("t2", country.toString());
    Log.d("t3", country.getText().toString());
}
```

Here is the log output:

```
02-07 05:10:16.877 23305-23305/---bundle id--- D/t1: t1
02-07 05:10:16.877 23305-23305/---bundle id--- D/t2: android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView{381dd943 V.ED..C. ......I. 0,0-0,0 #7f0e0089 app:id/country}
```

Comment: Is the content of the textview empty?

Comment: The first parameter is called the tag so you can search for it easily in the logcat

Comment: Empty strings can be just as useful as regular strings. I don't see why log was designed to not display if the second parameter is an empty string. In this case, I have to concatenate a second tag onto the second parameter in order for anything to display. /endrant

Comment: Worth noting that in the documentation the tag (first parameter)  *usually identifies the class or activity where the log call occurs.*

Comment: Good to know, more so for system generated logs. I'm used to NSLog just displaying whatever goes in it, but android does things very differently I'm learning. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome. My tags usually look like `MainActivity.class.getSimpleName()` which returns "MainActivity" and avoids the potential typo of a hard coded tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, if the `getText()` method of the `TextView` object returns an empty string, the logger will not output an entry for it. You can try concatenating some text to describe what should be expected in the output. For example:

```
Log.d("t3", "Country TextView Value: " + country.getText().toString());
```

Comment: I assumed that was what the first parameter was for. This works though. Thanks.

Comment: The `tag` parameter is used to identify the log message in the logs, it doesn't imply that it will show an entry if there's no value corresponding to it.

Answer (score 0):

This case is only possible with null string value return by `TextView`.
You need to add something with `Log` as below :

```
Log.d("t3", "Country : " + country.getText().toString());
```